# Bad quality plots when using gnuplot code inside LateX

Tags: gnuplot, sharelatex, gnuplottex

I am using the editor of www.sharelatex.com to compile my projects.
However, when i am writing my gnuplot code inside the project, the plots curves are not smooth.
Can you help me fixing it ?

```
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex, terminaloptions= color dashed,]

 set xlabel '$x$'
 set ylabel '$f(x)$'
 set samples 10000
 set key default
 set xrange[-10:10]
 set yrange[0:10]
 f(x) = exp(x**2)
 g(x) = 10*sin(x)/x
 set label '$f(x)=e^{x^2}$' at graph 0.53,0.3 rotate by 90 left
 set label '$g(x)=\frac{10sin(x)}{x}$' at graph 0.35,0.3 rotate by 80 left
 plot f(x) title '$e^{x^2}$' lw 2 lt 1 lc 7,\
 g(x) title '$\frac{10sin(x)}{x}$' lw 4 lt 1 lc 3

 \end{gnuplot}
```

here is the plot [image]

and here is the blue curve when i zoom in : 
[image]

Comment: If I use `set samples 1000000` I get a better output: [click here for the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9gUJ.png) There are still some artifacts, but they're due to the conversion to PNG; in the PDF the line is good.